# Why does my button not fire the onclick function after i search for it with a querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

**Basic HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class = "hitknop">Hit!</button>
</body>
<script src="index.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

**My JS**

```
const deckinit = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1";
const hitknoppie = document.querySelector("hitknop");
let deckId;


async function deckophalen(){
    const response = await fetch (deckinit);
    const deckopties = await response.json();
    deckId = deckopties.deck_id;
    console.log(deckId);
}

deckophalen();

hitknoppie.onclick = async function (){
    const kaartlink = `https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=1`;
    const response = await fetch (kaartlink);
    const kaart = await response.json();
    console.log(kaart);
}
```

I was expecting it to show the result of a single card, but it now just gives me the error that I cannot set properties of null `setting 'onclick'`.

I tried moving the script tag and adding defer to my `Js` document without success.

Comment: Because you are looking for an element with the _tag name_ `hitknop`, of which there are none.

Answer (score 2):

You must add . because you are calling a class. It must look like this:`const hitknoppie = document.querySelector(".hitknop");`

Comment: See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/g5yn4teo/1/